# How to update a lot of Firestore documents (over 100k)

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, cloud

I have to do some pretty heavy work once a month.

I have a "user" collection with over 100,000 documents.
One document is approximately 1kb.
And this collection is in sync with BigQuery.
I have to update all documents in this "user" collection once a month.

Users earn "point" the more they serve.
And users are given a new grade every month with these points.
Grades are given by a fixed percentage.
(For example, the top 10% is gold, 30% silver ...)

This is a method I came up with based on my lack of skills.

1. CloudFunction calls BigQuery, sorts all documents in the "user" collection by "point", and finds the minimum "point" required for each grade.
2. Using these "point" values, CloudFunction updates all Firestore documents.

Assuming I use this method,
How should I write the code for CloudFunction?
I don't need to change 100,000 documents in just seconds.
I don't mind if it takes a few minutes

For example, I think there's this way.

1. Update 1000 documents.
2. When it is complete, update the following 1000.
3. Next 1000...

But isn't the function terminated in this case?

How should I proceed....?
Additionally, there is no restriction that I must use Firebase Functions.

Plese Help..!
Thank you sincerely :)

Comment: [Firestore Bulkwriter](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/bulkwriter) might be useful with Cloud Functions.

Comment: @Dharmaraj
Thanks for the reply.
I read what you said.

Could you please tell me what is the difference between WriteBatch and Bulkwriter?
(I've used WriteBatch before)

Comment: As the `BulkWriter`  docs says "can be used to perform a large number of writes in parallel". With `WriteBatch` you are guaranteed the writes happen atomically (so they either all succeed, or none of them do), but not necessarily in parallel. Since your goal is to maximize the throughput, using `BulklWriter` would be a better fit.